# Permission denied when attempting to access generated protobufs using Uber Prototool

Tags: docker, go, protobuf-go

I am attempting to play around with https://github.com/uber/prototool that i came across. I created a simple repo called `protobufs` and wrote a simple script to generate my proto files in a docker container that pulls the image `uber-prototool. 
Code in`generate.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -rf gen

echo Generating Go code for all repos...

docker run --rm -v "$(pwd):/work" "uber/prototool:1.8.0" prototool generate proto
```

and also have a prototool.yaml file that looks like

```
excludes:
  - node_modules

protoc:
  version: 3.8.0

lint:
  group: uber2

  file_header:
    content: |
      //
      //
      //
    is_commented: true

generate:
  plugins:
    - name: go
      output: ../gen/go
      flags: plugins=grpc
```

I successfully generate the proto files but i get a `Permission Denied` when attempting to `cd` into the generated folder called `gen`. It's a hidden file and only can have access when i use `sudo`. It fails to show the hidden folder in `vscode` as well. I don't want to have to sudo into the hidden folder all the time and rather want a non root user to have access. How can i solve this?

Here is a screenshot of the repo being generated as a root user:
[image]

Comment: *sigh* `sudo` is not the *NIX way of  „I really mean what I am saying.“ It changes your euid to 0, making the process you start running as superuser. The docker image you are using obviously runs as root, hence the files generated by it belong to root (0==0 about everywhere ;)). Simply do a `sudo chown yourUser:yourGroup -r gen`

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg but it seems i will have to run this command `sudo chown yourUser:yourGroup -r gen` everytime i run the script which will override the user.

Comment: That is inherent by the use of Prototool from within a docker container. Simply add the chown part to your script or use one of the other installation methods.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg what other installation methods are you referring to?

Comment: https://github.com/uber/prototool/blob/dev/docs/install.md